# javascript alert if process is still running

Tags: javascript, perl, shell

I would like to know if its possible to create a javascript alert that will prompt users that there is previous form submitted and its still being processed or backend script is still running. The runtime process usually takes 2-5 mins.

excerpt of the html code below

```
            <form id="form" method="POST">
            <p id="survey">
                <label for="list"><b>Run survey to check number of NGPOS deployed</b></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="division">Please select division:</label>
                <select type="list" id="list" name="division">
                    <option>--Select One--</option>
                    <option value="DENVER">Denver</option>
                    <option value="PHOENIX_SOUTHWEST">Phoenix-Southwest</option>
                    <option value="PORTLAND">Portland</option>
                    <option value="SOUTHERN_HOUSTON">Southern-Houston</option>
                    <option value="NORCAL">Norcal</option>
                    <option value="SEATTLE">Seattle</option>
                    <option value="VONS_SoCal">Vons-Socal</option>
                    <option value="EASTERN">Eastern</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p id="survey">
                <input type="submit" value="Run Survey" onclick="surveyFunction();"/>
            </p>
            </form>
```

the javascript function is calling a perl script at the backend

```
function surveyFunction(){
var div = document.getElementById("list").value;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "possurv.pl",
    data: 'division=' + encodeURIComponent(div),
});
}
```

The perl script in turn executes a shell script and I added on the shell script a .sem file to prohibit multiple instances be executed. But the users on the frontend have no way of knowing this.

excerpt of perl script

```
$div = $FORM{division};

$expect = `./expect.sh $div`;
```

excerpt of shell script

```
sem="${log_path}/pos_survey.sem"

echo $0 "started."
if [ -e $sem ]
then
  echo $0 "still running, exiting."
  exit 1
else
  touch $sem
fi
```

Comment: You have a race condition on `if [ -e $sem ]`. What if two processes both see that the file isn't there?

Comment: @Karoly im sorry i didnt understand how is this. are you saying that if the process got executed at the same instance? there can only be one .sem file while process is running and at the end of the shell script it will delete this .sem file

Comment: Reaaaaally hope you're properly sanity/taint checking your inputs, God forbid someone alters the form to submit a division of `; rm / -rf`...

Comment: @Dren: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example

Comment: @Daniel even if someone alters the form i dont think that will be executed. the perl script calling the shell script is passing the variable thru this statement "sh survey/NGPsurvey.sh [lindex $argv 0]" i believe it would just error out, and on the shell script the variable should match a text file that will concatenate its contents.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind, but why not set a variable before your ajax query is sent that says you are processing and change the variable once the processing is finished and returns to the success function of your ajax query.

```
var processing = false;

function surveyFunction(){

    if(processing) {
        return alert('A survey is still being processed');
    }

    var div = document.getElementById("list").value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "possurv.pl",
        data: 'division=' + encodeURIComponent(div),
        beforeSend: function () {
            processing = true;
        },
        success: function() {                
            processing = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This lock only prevents access from the same page. E.g. If you open a new tab or another user connects, it's gone... The question doesn't specify whether this is OK, but since he's trying to do it in the backend, I assume it's not.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer didnt gave out a javascript alert when I tried and I havent figure out why but it also stopped calling the perlscript entirely.

Comment: @oceanexplorer Appreciate your help in this. The perl script is back running after including the missing comma, however there is still no javascript pop up message even i do the second submit on the same window browser, and i guess this will also not work if i open a different browser and submit the form there while there is still another submit being processed.

Comment: @Dren You are quite right that this is a simple solution that really only prevents the user from submitting the job multiple times. To cover the scenarios of multiple tabs, browsers, users you would have to implement something server side that check if a job is running and if so returns a result to the browser which can they display a message to the user. You could do this using the ajax query you have currently and adapting the server code. To help with the example I gave have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q8Qdb/363/ which mocks an ajax query lasting 3 seconds.

Comment: @Dren I know nothing of PERL but is your backend code actually return your ajax request when the work is complete? The success function in an ajax query gets called when the request is returned with a status code of 200.

Comment: @oceanexplorer not sure how can i can test ajax status code for that? what i know if it completed successfully because i made the perl script create a text file of the output i need and in turn have a javascript load and display the text file contents  as

 $('#check').hover(function(eIn){
  $('#survfeedback').load("finres.txt");
 }

Comment: @Dren In your browser open developer tools (Often F12 key) and look at the network tab, you may need to reload the page. There you will see all request and their status codes. Also in your Ajax call you can bind to an error event should it be failing and get a message

Answer (score 0):

**`jQuery Deferred`** or we called **`Promise`**:

> **deferred.always()**
>   Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected.

Example: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zguwnvwq/)**

Document: **[Deferred Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)**   and   **[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)**

```
var lock = false;
function surveyFunction() {
    if (lock) {
        console.debug('please wait');
        return false;
    }
    lock = true;
    var div = document.getElementById("list").value;
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "possurv.pl",
        data: 'division=' + encodeURIComponent(div)
    }).always(function () {
        console.debug('complete');
        lock = false
    });
}
```

Comment: This lock only prevents access from the same page. E.g. If you open a new tab or another user connects, it's gone... The question doesn't specify whether this is OK, but since he's trying to do it in the backend, I assume it's not.